# Django custom URL mapping: date pattern not matched in template

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 3.2

I have created a custom Date URL pattern matcher as follows:

#### helpers.py

```
from datetime import datetime

class DateConverter:
    regex = '\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return datetime.strptime(value, '%Y%m%d')

    def to_url(self, value):
        return value
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter

from . import views
from myproj.helpers import DateConverter

app_name = 'event'

register_converter(DateConverter, 'yyyymmdd')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('detail/<int:event_id>/<slug:event_slug>', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('archive/<yyyymmdd:start_date>/<yyyymmdd:end_date>', views.archive, name='archive'),        
]
```

#### index.html (relevant section)

```
  <div class="row">
    <a href="{% url 'event:archive' '2020101' '2020201' %}">Previous Events</a>
  </div>
```

I get the following error:

> reverse for 'archive' with arguments '('2020101', '2020201')' not
> found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['media/events/archive/(?P<start_date>\d{4}\d{2}\d{2})/(?P<end_date>\d{4}\d{2}\d{2})$']

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date strings are wrong. Indeed, it is interpreted as:

```
2020101
YYYYMMDD
```

It is thus missing a digit for the month, a correct date thus looks like:

```
{% url 'event:archive' '20200101' '20200201' %}"
```

Comment: Silly mistake on my part. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you're not passing enough digits in? Your DateConverter requires 4 + 2 + 2 = 8 digits and the numbers you are passing in only have 7 digits.